# Determining $U^°$ as a subspace of $V^*$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vectorspace over a field $F$ and let $U \subset V$ be a subspace. Define $$ U^° = \left\{l \in V^* \mid l(u) = 0 \quad \forall u \in U \right\}. $$

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $U = \text{span} \left\{v_1, v_2\right\}$ be the subspace of $V$ spanned by $v_1 = (2,1,0)$ and $v_2 = (1,1,-1)$. I need to determine $U^°$.

**Attempt:** Let $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Then $$ u = \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 $$ for some scalars $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in F$. Now we're looking for linear functionals $l \in V^*$ such that \begin{align*} l(u) = l (\lambda_1 (2,1,0) + \lambda_2 (1,1,-1)) = 0 \end{align*} or (because of linearity) \begin{align*} l(u) = \lambda_1 l(2,1,0) + \lambda_2 l(1,1,-1) = 0. \end{align*} Now I'm having problems with determining $l(2,1,0)$ and $l(1,1-1)$. I tried to find a dual basis to $\left\{v_1, v_2 \right\}$ but that didn't seem to help me.

Any suggestions/help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *any* basis of $V^*$, for instance the dual basis of the standard basis. An element $l\in V^*$ can be written
$$
\alpha_1e_1^*+\alpha_2e_2^*+\alpha_3e_3^*
$$
and so the conditions are
$$
\begin{cases}
(\alpha_1e_1^*+\alpha_2e_2^*+\alpha_3e_3^*)(2e_1+e_2)=0
\\[4px]
(\alpha_1e_1^*+\alpha_2e_2^*+\alpha_3e_3^*)(e_1+e_2-e_3)=0
\end{cases}
$$
that become
$$
\begin{cases}
2\alpha_1+\alpha_2=0
\\[4px]
\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3=0
\end{cases}
$$
We easily transform this into
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha_1=-\alpha_3
\\[4px]
\alpha_2=2\alpha_3
\end{cases}
$$
so a generator for $U^\circ$ is $-e_1^*+2e_2^*+e_3^*$, that is, the map having $[-1\ 2\ 1]$ as matrix.

Just check:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
=0
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

Comment: I see, thanks. So $\dim(U^°) = 3$?

Comment: @Kamil $\dim(U^\circ)$ is obviously $1$